# Diamond array sorting in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, memory

I have the following homework assignment in C. I basically need an approach rather than a solution.

We have a 13 x 13 array. In the array, we have a diamond shape that we need to consider. Everything outside this diamond is initialized to -1 (unimportant). Example 5 x 5 array below-

```
x x 1 x x 
x 2 2 2 x
3 3 3 3 3
x 4 4 4 x
x x 5 x x

x=-1
```

Now in this array, the values we have in the diamond for each entry contains 11 bits. 5 lsb contains one data (hue), and other 6 contains another data (diameter). We need to sort the data row-wise, monotonically for the hue, and then column-wise for the diameter, monotonically.

What would be the most efficient and memory conserving way of doing this? Since we need to conserve this, it's best if the entries are swapped around rather than creating another array. In the end, we will end up with a sorted diamond array (still with the -1s). Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Comment: Another one homework assignment...What have you tried sir?

Comment: randomize all the values, then check to see if they meet your requirements.  If they don't, repeat the process until they do.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: @xaxxon "How to efficiently check if the values are sorted?"

Comment: Can you give an example input with solution? In particular, if you care any two elements of the diamond, does hue "supercede" diameter? For example, say we represent an element as `(hue, diameter)` (assume they are just numbers for simplicity) then do we have `(1, 1000) < (2, 0)`? And would it be appropriate to say that you'd enumerate the elements of the diamond from top to bottom and, within a given row, left to right? If that's the case, then I would simply write a comparator function and sort the diamond as an array; or you can choose to sort by hue and then sort each row by diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand how exactly you want to reorder the elements

> row-wise, monotonically for the hue, and then column-wise for the diameter, monotonically

but here are some ideas you might be able to use.

- Your array is 13x13 (169 elements); out of that, almost exactly half (84) are empty, so you can use them as temporary storage (for e.g. [radix-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)).
- Your values have 11 meaningful bits; numbers in real computers have either 16 or 32 bits - so you can use the 5 (or 21, depending on your system) most significant bits as temporary storage.
- One possibly good way to use the upper 5 bits is putting a copy of the 5 LSB (hue) there. This will reverse the significance of the two parts when doing normal integer comparison (making hue more significant than diameter)

Comment: thanks anatolyg, that was a really helpful tip to just use the other half as storage. I'll give this a shot and get back to you guys. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

I see.
I suppose such a diamond shape could be directly represented by an array.
Ignore all the **-1** entries.

```
{ row-0 row-1 row-2 row-3 ... row-13 }

{ 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 }
```

You can now sort the array as you like.
Sort it twice, once for hue, once for diameter; or figure out how to sort an array by two criteria.

You can also work in-place, if you just write a function for converting an array index to diamond-coordinates. With that done, you can just work on the diamond-structure as if it was an array.

Comment: I think I have it guys. I first sorted them by column with-

Answer (score 0):

Write a sorting routine with this prototype:

```
void sort(int startx, int starty, int dx, int dy, int count, int (*compare)(int, int));
```

or

```
void sort(int *start, int stride, int count, int (*compare)(int,int));
```

Write a couple of comparison functions, and call sort in two for loops, one for rows and another for columns.