# MIPS Diamond Sorting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, memory, mips

I have the following diamond array in memory, starting at base address 5000.  The first valid value is positioned at 5008 (index 2), and all other values are positioned relative to it.

```
 .  .  4  .  .
 .  3  7  8  .
 2  2  9  8  5
 .  1  5  9  .
 .  .  3  .  .
```

All of the values represented as "." in the array are uninitialized, so they should not be accessed.

Now the problem.  I need to sort this array in MIPS without accessing the uninitialized values in memory.  I can't create a new array with all of the valid indices of the diamond because of memory constraints.  So basically, I'm stuck.

Comment: sorting means you want `[-,-,4,-,-,-,3,7,8,-,2,2,9,8,5,-,1,5,9,-,-,-,3,-,-]` to become `[-,-,1,-,-,-,2,2,3,-,3,4,5,5,7,-,8,8,9,-,-,-,9,-,-]`?

Comment: @WalterTross Yes, exactly.

Comment: Do you at least have the place for allocating an array of N values where N is the side of the square (N=5 in your example)? Or maybe 2 such arrays?

Comment: @WalterTross Yes I do.

Comment: My attempt is below. By using the `clz` instruction I've been able to do without a lookup table. I have not tested the pseudocode, so there might still be some typo. Let me know if something doesn't seem right, or if I should make something clearer.

Comment: See this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248145/diamond-array-sorting-in-c

Comment: My attempt had a flaw, so I deleted it. BTW, if this is homework, it's most effective when done alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row of cell `k` can be calculated as:

```
row(k) = k < (S+1)*(S+1)/4 ? isqrt(k) : S - 1 - isqrt((S*S-1)/2 - k)
```

The indent of row `n` in the diamond array is:

```
indent(n) = abs((S - 1)/2 - n)
```

The cell where row `n` starts at is:

```
start(n) = n < S/2 ? n*n : (S*S+1)/2 - (S-n)*(S-n)
```

Combining these, you can calculate the index of cell `k`:

```
index(k) = row(k)*S + indent(n) + (k - start(row(k)))
```

**Example:**

```
S = 5
. . # . .
. # # # .
# # # # #
. # # # .
. . # . .

cell    row     indent  start   index
0       0       2       0       2
1       1       1       1       6
2       1       1       1       7
3       1       1       1       8
4       2       0       4       10
5       2       0       4       11
6       2       0       4       12
7       2       0       4       13
8       2       0       4       14
9       3       1       9       16
10      3       1       9       17
11      3       1       9       18
12      4       2       12      22
```

Using this, you could easily implement [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

```c
/// Calculates the index of cell k in a diamond array of size S.
int index(int k, int S)
{
    int row = k < (S+1)*(S+1)/4 ? isqrt(k) : S - 1 - isqrt((S*S-1)/2 - k);
    int indent = abs((S - 1)/2 - row);
    int start = n < S/2 ? n*n : (S*S+1)/2 - (S-n)*(S-n);
    return row*S + indent + (k - start);
}

/// Sorts the diamond array data, of size S.
void diamondSelectionSort(int[] data, int S)
{
    int total = (S*S+1)/2;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        int indexI = index(i,S);

        int bestCell = i;
        int bestIndex = indexI;
        int bestValue = data[bestIndex];

        for (int j = i+1; j < total; j++)
        {
            int indexJ = index(j,S);

            if (data[indexJ] < bestValue)
            {
                bestCell = j;
                bestIndex = indexJ;
                bestValue = data[indexJ];
            }
        }
    }

    if (bestIndex > i)
    {
        data[bestIndex] = data[indexI];
        data[indexI] = bestValue;
    }
}

/// Integer square root. Adopted from
/// http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/factoring/isqrt.c.html
int isqrt (int x)
{
    if (x < 1) return 0;

    int squaredbit = (int) ((((unsigned int) ~0) >> 1) & 
            ~(((unsigned int) ~0) >> 2));
    int remainder = x;
    int root = 0;
    while (squaredbit > 0) {
        if (remainder >= (squaredbit | root)) {
            remainder -= (squaredbit | root);
            root = (root >> 1) | squaredbit;
        } else {
            root >>= 1;
        }
        squaredbit >>= 2; 
    }

    return root;
}
```

---

`index()` could be unrolled a little:

```
/// Calculates the index of cell k in a diamond array of size S.
int index(int k, int S)
{
    int row, indent, start;
    if (k < (S+1)*(S+1)/4)
    {
        row = isqrt(k);
        indent = (S - 1)/2 - row;
        start = n*n;
    }
    else
    {
        row = S - 1 - isqrt((S*S-1)/2 - k);
        indent = row - (S - 1)/2;
        start = (S*S+1)/2 - (S-n)*(S-n);
    }
    return row*S + indent + (k - start);
}
```